# Building numpy/scipy for Python3 on Mac OS Lion

Tags: macos, numpy, python-3.x, scipy, importerror

I can't get [Numpy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy) or [Scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) to work with Python3 on MAC OSX Lion.

I have used pip successfully to install numpy, scipy and matplotlib, and they work well with Python2.7, but in Python3 typing `import numpy` brings up `No module named numpy`. I've tried downloading the source code directly and then running 'python3 setup.py build', but I get various error warnings, some in red that have to do with fortran (e.g. 'Could not locate executable f95'). The error message that appears to fail in the end is 'RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program', and appears to be related to the previous line 'sh: gcc-4.2: command not found'.

The [Scipy website](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X) suggests that there may be issues with the c compiler, but the same problems didn't arise using pip to install for python2.7. I have followed the instructions on the website regarding changing the compiler but this has not made any difference.

I have also tried installing from a virtual environment:

```
mkvirtualenv -p python3.2 test1
pip install numpy
```

But this fails with `Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /Users/Eddy/.virtualenvs/test1/build/numpy`

I've considered making python3 default, and then I thought a pip install might work, but I don't know how to do that. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I might proceed? Thanks.

Comment: I've now got scipy et al working on Python2.7, I followed the instructions here: http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/, though for scipy itself I had to a) download the source myself, b) install umfpack by typing 'brew install umfpack', and c) run 'python setup.py build' and 'python setup.py install' from the scipy directory.

Comment: The same technique has not been successful with python3. Going to the numpy directory and typing 'python3 setup.py build' gives the message 'this is the wrong setup.py file to run'. Opening a VirtualEnv test and 'pip install numpy' fails too with an egg_info error code 1, whatever that is.

Comment: I've succeeded in building numpy from source for Python 3 on Linux. I suggest you grab the source tarball ([on PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy)) and try with setup.py. If you get the 'wrong setup.py file' message, you're using the wrong setup.py file ;). You need the one in the top directory of the source.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I've downloaded the source code (I tried going direct with the tar, and now I've tried a git clone as recommended on http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X). I'm also now using the correct setup.py ;-)

Now when I do 'python3 setup.py build' it fails after the final warning: "RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program". This appears to be linked to the line in the output that says: "sh: gcc-4.2: command not found". There are also red output lines complaining: "Could not locate executable f95" (amongst others, but almost all fortran related).

Comment: The scipy website (http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X) does say that the Lion bundled C compiler has difficulties, and I followed its suggestions to change from llvm-gcc-4.2 to gcc-4.2, but I'm not sure if it worked. "gcc -version" gives me:

"i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)" + some more legal stuff.

Comment: Sorry, can't help with Mac specific stuff. You might try asking on the scipy-user mailing list, I'm sure people will know about it.

Comment: Oh, didn't see that you'd commented again (I didn't notice the 'show one more comment' link). Thanks again, I'll try them.

Comment: Your question confuses me. You want to install it in both py2 and py3?

Comment: Sorry Warren, only just saw your question. Yes, I have it working in py2, but would like to get it working in py3. I'd like to switch to py3 completely, but cannot if I can't get scipy to work on it.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue of 
scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/*superlumodule.c:268:9: error: non-void function 'PyInit*_superlu' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]

someone on the scipy mailing list suggested the following:

```
what happens if you change the line 268 ( in scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlumodule.c)

from 
return;

to 
return NULL;
```

sure enough it worked

Comment: I wish I could give you more upvotes.  This has now also been fixed in scipy (master) on github.

Answer (score 1):

I've made some progress with this problem, with much assistance from Ned Deily on the pythonmac mailing list. I can now build numpy for python3, but scipy still won't build.

To install numpy:
The scipy website (http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X) suggests working around the C compiler problem with three typed commands, but these are insufficient, you need one more:

```
$ export CC=clang
$ export CXX=clang
$ export FFLAGS=-ff2c
$ export LDSHARED='clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup \
-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g'
```

After this building from source should work. See [here](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/Building-numpy-scipy-for-python3-on-MacOS-Lion-td4642828.html) for details.

Problem building scipy:
I don't know what the issue here is, something with the C compiler again though I think. Here are the error messages. I'd greatly appreciate any thoughts on this matter.

Thanks, Eddy

error messages:

```
compiling C sources 

C compiler: clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk 

compile options: '-DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DUSE_VENDOR_BLAS=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/include/python3.2m -c' 
extra options: '-msse3' 
clang: scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlumodule.c 
In file included from scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlumodule.c:18: 
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:15: 
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17: 
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1972: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_deprecated_api.h:11:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API" [-W#warnings] 
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API" 
 ^ 
scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlumodule.c:268:9: error: non-void function 'PyInit__superlu' should return a value [-Wreturn-type] 
        return; 
        ^ 
1 warning and 1 error generated. 
In file included from scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlumodule.c:18: 
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:15: 
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17: 
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1972: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_deprecated_api.h:11:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API" [-W#warnings] 
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API" 
 ^ 
scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlumodule.c:268:9: error: non-void function 'PyInit__superlu' should return a value [-Wreturn-type] 
        return; 
        ^ 
1 warning and 1 error generated. 
error: Command "clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DUSE_VENDOR_BLAS=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/include/python3.2m -c scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlumodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.2/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlumodule.o -msse3" failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I was able to install scipy 0.10.1 with python3 on 10.7 without doing anything special (other than downloading the source and using `setup.py install` instead of pip/easy_install, and using gfortran from homebrew).

Comment: No I haven't managed to get it to work yet. Did you have to specify gfortran some other way? I'm happy with python 2 for now but I may try again later in the year when the new scipy is out.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it just worked without doing anything at all (setting environment variables or anything).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and one of these sorted it - not sure which one but I include both for completeness:

1. I had this in my .bash_profile "export CC=gcc-4.2" which was probably some kind of hack from previous OS X compilation problems, I removed it.
2. Installed the standalone GCC from here https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/ over my XCode install

booted up a new terminal window and `pip install numpy` worked fine